# Html (with images) to PDF - Java

Tags: java, html-to-pdf

I have tried using Flying Saucer to convert html to pdf.
Somehow it coverts the pain text only.
I'm having images (img tags) and I want them too.
This is what I did. How do I make this for images?

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new File("sampleData.htm"));

    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocument(doc, "");
    renderer.layout();
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    renderer.createPDF(os);
```

Thank you!

Comment: [YaHP](http://www.allcolor.org/YaHPConverter/) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this might be a late reply but I still if it can help someone. Images are not supported internally in itext api. you have to explicitly tell the itext to include tags like   like that. I am giving you the link you can refer to http://www.samuelrossille.com/home/category/java for a clear understanding. And if you need any working code I can help you just let me know.

Answer (score -1):

I faced similar issue with another PDF converter some time back. This could the problem when you images are relative to current directory.

Here is what you can do:

```
String curDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Try pasting the images in `curDir` and remove the relative path. Once this works, you can adjust you paths appropriately.

Comment: Sorry,I don't understand. I just parse the .htm file. Where can I apply this curDir ?